# Scala: How to make multiple methods and apply them one by one?

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

Scala: How to make multiple methods and apply them one by one?

I have a list: `List("1", "2", "3")`

and a method:

```
def concat(str: String)(tail: String): String = str + tail
```

My aim is to make three (imaginary) methods:

```
concat(str: String)("1")
concat(str: String)("2")
concat(str: String)("3")
```

and then apply these three methods one by one to a test string "abc":
then I'll have the result: `"abc123"`

What is the functional way to do this? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need 3 different methods.  Just use `fold` to traverse your list and apply your `concat` method successively:

```
val list = List("1", "2", "3")

def concat(str: String)(tail: String): String = str + tail

list.fold( "abc" )( concat(_)(_) )
// res1: String = abc123
```

Note that `fold( "abc" )( concat(_)(_) )` is just a shortcut for:

```
fold( "abc" )( (acc, x) => concat(acc)(x) )
```

In case you aren't familiar with `fold`, here's the [API doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#fold[A1%3E:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1)